# Not override a file when used as stdout of a c program

Tags: terminal, make, gcc, output, input

I have used `gcc` and `make` to compile a `c` file.
The name of the run file is `sequence`. I have two goals:

1. Have an input file (i.e`in1`) as `stdin` and run the program. when the program finishes using in1 and terminates, run it again with a different input file (i.e `in2` specified in the terminal command.
2. Have all the outputs from all the different times the program executed go to the same file (i.e`output1`), without overriding the previous inputs.
   So the result will be something like this:

#### Input files:

`in1`:

```
a
```

`in2`:

```
b
```

`in3`

```
c
```

In program:

```
putchar(getchar());
```

#### Output:

```
a
b
c
```

How can I achieve the expected result via terminal command?

Comment: Please see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators) in particular look at the answer section(s) concerning **Redirection Operators**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up what is the responsibility of the shell, and the responsibility of a program.

## You have two choices

### Have the program open 3 files, and write them to stdout. This is what cat does.

```
program in1 in2 in3
```

### Use shell-redirection-append `>>`.

E.g.

```
program <in1 >> file-name
program <in2 >> file-name
program <in3 >> file-name
```

or use brackets, and over-writing-redirection

```
{
  program <in1
  program <in2
  program <in3
} > file-name
```